# Text-To-Columns in macro converts 24 time into 12h format

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro which does Text-To-Columns function( divides date and time stored in one column into two other columns, one for date and one for time).

However, when I perform this function directly in Excel, I receive the desired output: date + time in 24h format but when I run exactly the same procedure recorded as a macro the output is: date + time in 12h format. An additional third column is created with AM/PM mark. The macro works for few cells correctly but for few it does not.

The original file:

[image: 'original data']

The output without macro(this is how I need the output with macro):

[image: 'without macro']

The output with macro:

[image: <code>With macro</code>]

Can you please suggest me how to resolve this?

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
                        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:= _
                        Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Then add a line that formats the date time as preferred after the texttocolumns.

Comment: After text to columns the data is separated in three columns.So the formatting does not work until the AM/PM is in the same second column for time identification.

Comment: What are your Windows Regional Settings for short date format?  MDY or DMY?  Is the actual CSV file, when opened with a text editor, the same as your "original data"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a macro recorder error. Try this code:

```
Sub ExtractTime()
'
' Extract time from date
'

'
    Dim Target As Range
    For Each Target In Selection
        If IsDate(Target) Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value - Int(Target.Value)
            Target.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
            Target.Value = Int(Target.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a known issue raised already on [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-does-text-to-columns-return-time-in-12-hour/85e6d07b-7f5b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) forum. Anyway, switching from `DataType:=xlDelimited` to `DataType:=xlFixedWidth` seems to do the trick:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the update Monty. I wonder why it didn't work for you - as you can see on my screenshot, it worked for me. Did you select the entire column A before running the macro? What is the result (did the macro return an error, or did it run but the output is incorrect)?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your Windows Regional Settings are MDY, and the CSV file is formatted as DMY.

What happens:

- The dates where `D` <= 12 get interpreted as real dates (albeit **incorrectly**), and when written into the cell, get translated to real dates in the format of `m/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM`
- The dates where `D` > 12 get interpreted as strings, and do not have the `AM/PM` appended.

When you do your `TTC`, the "real dates" have two spaces, so have the `AM/PM` in the third column.  The "strings" only have one space, so get split as you show it.

The dates that are being interpreted as dates are probable being interpreted incorrectly. In other words, your `1-10-2019` is thought by Excel to be `Jan 10, 2019` whereas it should be `1-Oct-2019`.

Aside from a complicated VBA routine, the `Fix` for this problem is to properly **Import** the data so the dates get interpreted correctly before they get to the worksheet.

You can do this with either the Legacy import wizard, or with Power Query.

Using either one, you can split on the space, and specify that the dates are `DMY`, and then format both the date and the time however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old but if anyone have the same issue, code below solves it:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 2), Array(3,9))
```

This part of code says that column 1 is a date, column 2 (hour) is a text and column 3 (if will appear as am/pm) is skipped. Works for me. And you can add as much Array() as you wish even if there are no columns to skip.